# Netbeans: deploying Java app to remote Tomcat

Tags: netbeans

Is there any easy way to automatically deploy a web service / java web app, etc to a remote tomcat server? currently i have to manually copy the .war file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I add a "deploy" target in build.xml that contains an <scp> tag to transfer the war file.

UPDATE:

Here is an example:

```
<target name="deploy" depends="dist">
    <scp todir="${user.name}@www.myserver.com:tomcat-base/webapps/"
            keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/myserver.key"
            passphrase="BlaBlaBla" trust="true">
        <fileset dir="dist" includes="myapp.war"/>
    </scp>
</target>
```

Comment: could you go into more detail here, please?