# Deploy webapp on remote tomcat server from netbeans

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, deployment

Is it possible to deploy a service on a remote tomcat server from within local netbeans IDE?

I am using tomcat 6.0.35 on remote windows 2003 server and Netbeans IDE 7.0.1

Comment: You can find about it  [here][1]:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781057/how-to-deploy-to-tomcat-from-netbeans

Comment: No, that link doesn't help much, user1214083. The UI still doesn't let you define remote servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could modify your build script (Solutions for [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554249/maven-remote-tomcat-configuration) and [Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056829/netbeans-deploying-java-app-to-remote-tomcat) can be found here at SO)